CoreWCF - The service implementation object was not initialized or is not available
I have built a CoreWCF project that is running and I can access the WSDL from the browser, but when I try to connect to it from my test client console app, I get the error: "The service implementation object was not initialized or is not available."
and then in the client output I see: Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1' in System.ServiceModel.Primitives.dll
The error suggests maybe I'm not doing something right with registering the services for dependency injection but I can't seem to get any more details in the error that indicate which service is the problem. Thanks for any help here!
Here is the service project code:
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}

public class Startup
{
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddServiceModelServices();
        services.AddServiceModelMetadata();
        services.AddSingleton<IServiceBehavior, UseRequestHeadersForMetadataAddressBehavior>();

        services.AddServicesForDI();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseServiceModel(serviceBuilder =>
        {       
            serviceBuilder.AddService<AssetManagementService>(serviceOptions =>
            {
                serviceOptions.DebugBehavior.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;
            })
            .AddServiceEndpoint<AssetManagementService, IAssetManagementService>(new BasicHttpBinding(), "/AssetManagementService.svc");

            var serviceMetadataBehavior = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
            serviceMetadataBehavior.HttpGetEnabled = true;
        });
    }
}

public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddServicesForDI(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //DI
            services.AddScoped<IInsightDataAccess, InsightDataAccess>();

            services.AddScoped<IInsightSetting, InsightSetting>();
            services.AddScoped<SettingEntity>();
            services.AddScoped<IAssetManagementService, AssetManagementService>();
        }
    }

 [ServiceContract]
    public interface IAssetManagementService
    {
      [OperationContract]
      List<SettingEntity> GetSettings(); 
    }

 public class AssetManagementService : IAssetManagementService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<AssetManagementService> m_logger;

        public AssetManagementService(ILogger<AssetManagementService> logger )
        {
            m_logger = logger;
        }
        public List<SettingEntity> GetSettings()
        {
            try
            {
                return new List<SettingEntity>(); //m_insightSetting.GetSettings();
            }
            catch (ArgumentException e)
            {
                // Log the exception.
                m_logger.LogError(e, "Error in GetSettings");
                throw new FaultException(new FaultReason(e.Message));
            }
            catch (FaultException ex)
            {
                // I always end up here....
                Console.WriteLine($"Failed with '{ex.Message}'");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                m_logger.LogError(ex, "Error in GetSettings");
                throw;
            }
        
            return new List<SettingEntity>();
        }
    }

[DataContract]
    public class SettingEntity : EntityBase
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int SettingId { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string SettingName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string SettingValue { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string SettingDatatype { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public bool Critical { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Group { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public bool ChangeWhenMovingEnvironments { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public bool IsEditable { get; set; }
    }

Client project code:
static async Task Main()
{
    await ExecuteAssetManagement();
    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate client.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static async Task ExecuteAssetManagement()
{
    AssetManagementServiceClient client = new AssetManagementServiceClient();
    GetSettingsRequest request = new GetSettingsRequest();
    try
    {
        var response = await client.GetSettingsAsync(request);
        Console.WriteLine("Return value: ({0}", response.GetSettingsResult.ToString());
    }
    catch (FaultException ex)
    {
        // I always end up here....
        Console.WriteLine($"Failed with '{ex.Message}'");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Failed with '{ex.Message}'");
    }

    client.CloseAsync();
}


ASP.NET Core project does not support System.ServiceModel.Primitives now. You can try CoreWCF.Primitives in your project.
